# Sort folders in the Terminal in alphabetical order

Tags: wildcards, macos

I made a loop to go to each directory so that it executes a command. But I noticed that the entry in the folders is not in alphabetical order.

The loop goes like this:

```
#1/
#10/
#11/
#12/
#13/
#14/
#15/
#16/
#17/
#18/
#19/
#2/
#20/
#3/
#4/
#5/
#6/
#7/
#8/
#9/
...
```

But you must:

```
#1/
#2/
#3/
#4/
...
```

My script

```
for d in */; do echo "$d"; (cd "$d" && ls); done;
```

Answer (score 1):

They *are* in alphabetical order. In alphabetical order, `2` comes after `10` because `2` comes after `1`, just like `B` comes after `AB`. Here you want a *numerical* order instead of an alphabetical order.

To do that, make sure you use the `zsh` shell (should be the default user shell in the latest version of macos) and use:

```
for d in *(N/n); do (cd -- $d && print -r -- $d && ls); done
```

Or with the short form:

```
for d (*(N/n)) (cd -- $d && print -r -- $d && ls)
```

The `(N/n)` part are *glob qualifiers*:

- `N`: expands to nothing if there's no match instead of reporting an error (`nullglob` option enabled for that one glob).
- `/`: selects only files of type *directory*
- `n`: toggles numeric sorting for the glob expansion (`numericglobsort` option enabled for that one glob).

You could also toggle `numericglobsort` on globally (`set -o numericglobsort`) if you find yourself generally preferring that order, and then you could got back to using your `for d in */; ...`.

Note that `*(/)` is not exactly the same as `*/`. `*(/)` expands to all the files of type *directory*, while `*/` selects files of type *directory* or *symlink to directory* and appends a `/`, so `*/` is more like `*(-/M)` (the `-` glob qualifier makes the subsequent qualifiers apply *after* symlink resolution, and `M` is to *mark* files of type directory (here after symlink resolution) with `/`).

Comment: Oh my god, it works !!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your simple approach and folders, you can separate by number of digits:

```
for d in ?/;  do echo "$d"; (cd "$d" && ls); done
for d in ??/; do echo "$d"; (cd "$d" && ls); done
```

This duplication of code is of course not very nice. But then again, you give no context at all, except "you must #1 #2 #3".

Or maybe:

```
for d in {1..20}; do echo "$d"; (cd "$d" && ls); done
```

(works also with a slash after `{1..20}/`)

This makes only sense if you have all the numbers as folders.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for d in $(find * -type d | sort -g); do echo "$d";(cd "$d" && ls);done;
```